# find sum of first 3 sorted rows and check for sum more than 1000

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a `transaction` table with columns as `sender`, `receiver`, `date` and `amount` I want to find all the name of receivers whose records sum is atleast 1000 in no more than 3 transactions.

**Example:**

```
sender, receiver, date, amount
A, B, 2020-01-01, 500
C, B, 2020-01-01, 500 
D, B, 2020-21-01, 200
A, C, 2021-01-01, 400
D, C, 2021-01-01, 60
A, D, 2021-01-01, 4000
C, A, 2019-01-01, 50
D, A, 2019-02-01, 50
B, A, 2019-03-01, 50
E, A, 2019-04-01, 50
```

**Ans:**

```
B, D. Answer in sorted name order
```

**Explanation:**
B receives 1000 in just 2 transactions. D received > 1000 in just 1 transaction.

I know how to group the records based on name but dont know how to find the sum of 3 records and check if more than 1000.

Comment: *sum is atleast 1000 in no more than 3 transactions* ANY 3 transactions? regardless of the date?

Comment: @Akina, yes any date

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas, what sql command can i use to know the version of mysql?

Comment: `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @Akina, it says 5.7.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT receiver, amount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY amount DESC) rn
    FROM transaction 
)
SELECT receiver
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY receiver
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 1000
```

Comment: looks like my version of mysql is not allowing me to use `with cte`.

Answer (score 0):

The following applies to MySQL 8+ (the 5.7 was not in t he original question or the original tag).

You can use `row_number()` to order the transactions in descending order by amount.  Then aggregate:

```
select receiver
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by receiver order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by receiver
having sum(amount) >= 1000;
```

In older versions, you will probably need to enumerate the rows using variables, because you could have ties in the data:

```
select receiver
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@r = receiver, @rn + 1,
                        if(@r := receiver, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from (select t.* from t order by receiver, amount desc) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @r := '') params
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by receiver
having sum(amount) >= 1000;
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error near `(partition by receiver order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where ` looks like partion is not working. But I am not sure

Comment: @learner . . . I see you added a tag for an older version of MySQL.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql variables to count row number then filter based on row number like that

```
set @current_client := '';
set @row_count = 0;
select receiver, sum(amount) as total from (select receiver,amount,  
case 
    when  @current_client = receiver then @row_count := @row_count+1 
    when @current_client !=  receiver THEN @row_count := 1 
end as tmp1,
case  when @current_client !=  receiver THEN @current_client := receiver end as tmp2,
@row_count as row_number 
FROM transaction  order by transaction.receiver asc, transaction.amount desc
) as tmp
where row_number <= 3
group by receiver
having total >= 1000
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8e6d5/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by receiver` and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to collect all amounts for each `receiver` in descending order in a comma separated list.
Then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract the top 3 amounts and add them to check if their sum is equal or greater than 1000:

```
SELECT receiver
FROM (
  SELECT receiver, 
         COUNT(*) counter,
         GROUP_CONCAT(amount ORDER BY amount DESC) amounts
  FROM tablename       
  GROUP BY receiver
) t  
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(amounts, ',', 1) +
      CASE WHEN counter > 1 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(amounts, ',', 2), ',', -1) ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN counter > 2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(amounts, ',', 3), ',', -1) ELSE 0 END 
      >= 1000;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2181830da3013a2c8c0f2de5a24ddd19).

Of course this does not scale well for more than 3 amounts.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT receiver, amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY receiver) AS ranking
FROM transactions
)

SELECT receiver, sum(amount) as total_received
FROM A
WHERE ranking IN (1,2,3)
group by receiver
HAVING sum(amount) >= 1000
```